# Bootstrap image auto resize doesn't works in left column

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have standard 3 column layout with similar img in left and right column. When I resize page, right image becomes smaller but left not. And middle container overflow left image.

Css for image resizing:

```
   img {
      display: block;
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
```

My full code is:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>
    .logo_item {
      display: inline-block;
      margin-left: 2.5em;
      margin-right: 2.5em;
    }
    img {
      display: block;
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- 2nd row -->
    <div class="row mt-4">
      <div class="brd_black col">
        <div style="position:fixed;">
          <a href="javascript:window.history.back();"><img src="https://v1.iconsearch.ru/uploads/icons/crystalclear/64x64/folder_home.png" /></a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="brd_black col-10">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="brd_black col-12 bg-white align-top brd_grey pb-3 pt-3 text-center">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras id lacus sit amet leo feugiat venenatis. Donec mattis erat eget velit dapibus, at consequat nisi pretium. Nulla ut elementum ex, in rutrum neque. Integer eu blandit sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi vitae pulvinar odio. Morbi fermentum dolor sapien, vitae semper est maximus non. Vestibulum bibendum aliquet lacinia. Nullam sollicitudin auctor metus vel pretium. Donec fermentum ligula suscipit metus varius dictum. Curabitur ultrices justo at arcu cursus, sit amet iaculis dolor dapibus. Morbi semper porta nunc. Aliquam rutrum congue nunc non facilisis.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="brd_black col">
        <div style="position:fixed;">
          <a href="faq.html"><img src="https://v1.iconsearch.ru/uploads/icons/crystalclear/64x64/folder_home.png" target="_blank" /></a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But why?

Comment: do you need position fixed?.. its because of that..remove position css to make it work as you want

Comment: Or use `position:absolute;` instead of fixed position.

Comment: I need fixed postion because in real page there are a lot of texts. Anyway i don't really understand why the same code works at right column and not in left.

Comment: right column dont have position property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>
    .logo_item {
      display: inline-block;
      margin-left: 2.5em;
      margin-right: 2.5em;
    }
    img {
      display: block;
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
    .bg_img
    {
      background: url('https://v1.iconsearch.ru/uploads/icons/crystalclear/64x64/folder_home.png')no-repeat center center;
      display: block;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      background-size: contain;
      float: left;
      position: fixed;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- 2nd row -->
    <div class="row mt-4">
      <div class="brd_black col">
        <div>
          <a href="javascript:window.history.back();" class="bg_img"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="brd_black col-10">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="brd_black col-12 bg-white align-top brd_grey pb-3 pt-3 text-center">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras id lacus sit amet leo feugiat venenatis. Donec mattis erat eget velit dapibus, at consequat nisi pretium. Nulla ut elementum ex, in rutrum neque. Integer eu blandit sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi vitae pulvinar odio. Morbi fermentum dolor sapien, vitae semper est maximus non. Vestibulum bibendum aliquet lacinia. Nullam sollicitudin auctor metus vel pretium. Donec fermentum ligula suscipit metus varius dictum. Curabitur ultrices justo at arcu cursus, sit amet iaculis dolor dapibus. Morbi semper porta nunc. Aliquam rutrum congue nunc non facilisis.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="brd_black col">
        <div>
          <a href="faq.html" class="bg_img"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Images are small at the big screen - not the point. The idea is to make them auto-resized.

Comment: set `width: 6vw;  height: 6vw;`  instead of  ` width: 20px; height: 20px;`

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot - it works in IE, FF, Safari and Chrome.

Comment: The only trouble - bg image in vw, vh or em displayed not as sharp as original. But, anyway, it's a best solution provided here.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `position:fixed` style from the div.
 
I have tried your code and removed your `img` tag styles and replaced it with the default `img-fluid` class of bootstrap-4 and it's working fantastic.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>
    .logo_item {
      display: inline-block;
      margin-left: 2.5em;
      margin-right: 2.5em;
    }

    .sticky {
      position: sticky;
      position: -webkit-sticky !important;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 1030;
      display: flex;
    }

    .stick_img{
      position: sticky;
      position: -webkit-sticky !important;
      top: 15px;

    }

  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- 2nd row -->
    <div class="row mt-4">
      <div class="brd_black col sticky">
        <div>
          <a href="javascript:window.history.back();"><img src="https://v1.iconsearch.ru/uploads/icons/crystalclear/64x64/folder_home.png" class="img-fluid stick_img" /></a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="brd_black col-10">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="brd_black col-12 bg-white align-top brd_grey pb-3 pt-3 text-center">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras id lacus sit amet leo feugiat venenatis. Donec mattis erat eget velit dapibus, at consequat nisi pretium. Nulla ut elementum ex, in rutrum neque. Integer eu blandit sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi vitae pulvinar odio. Morbi fermentum dolor sapien, vitae semper est maximus non. Vestibulum bibendum aliquet lacinia. Nullam sollicitudin auctor metus vel pretium. Donec fermentum ligula suscipit metus varius dictum. Curabitur ultrices justo at arcu cursus, sit amet iaculis dolor dapibus. Morbi semper porta nunc. Aliquam rutrum congue nunc non facilisis.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras id lacus sit amet leo feugiat venenatis. Donec mattis erat eget velit dapibus, at consequat nisi pretium. Nulla ut elementum ex, in rutrum neque. Integer eu blandit sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi vitae pulvinar odio. Morbi fermentum dolor sapien, vitae semper est maximus non. Vestibulum bibendum aliquet lacinia. Nullam sollicitudin auctor metus vel pretium. Donec fermentum ligula suscipit metus varius dictum. Curabitur ultrices justo at arcu cursus, sit amet iaculis dolor dapibus. Morbi semper porta nunc. Aliquam rutrum congue nunc non facilisis.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras id lacus sit amet leo feugiat venenatis. Donec mattis erat eget velit dapibus, at consequat nisi pretium. Nulla ut elementum ex, in rutrum neque. Integer eu blandit sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi vitae pulvinar odio. Morbi fermentum dolor sapien, vitae semper est maximus non. Vestibulum bibendum aliquet lacinia. Nullam sollicitudin auctor metus vel pretium. Donec fermentum ligula suscipit metus varius dictum. Curabitur ultrices justo at arcu cursus, sit amet iaculis dolor dapibus. Morbi semper porta nunc. Aliquam rutrum congue nunc non facilisis.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras id lacus sit amet leo feugiat venenatis. Donec mattis erat eget velit dapibus, at consequat nisi pretium. Nulla ut elementum ex, in rutrum neque. Integer eu blandit sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi vitae pulvinar odio. Morbi fermentum dolor sapien, vitae semper est maximus non. Vestibulum bibendum aliquet lacinia. Nullam sollicitudin auctor metus vel pretium. Donec fermentum ligula suscipit metus varius dictum. Curabitur ultrices justo at arcu cursus, sit amet iaculis dolor dapibus. Morbi semper porta nunc. Aliquam rutrum congue nunc non facilisis.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras id lacus sit amet leo feugiat venenatis. Donec mattis erat eget velit dapibus, at consequat nisi pretium. Nulla ut elementum ex, in rutrum neque. Integer eu blandit sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi vitae pulvinar odio. Morbi fermentum dolor sapien, vitae semper est maximus non. Vestibulum bibendum aliquet lacinia. Nullam sollicitudin auctor metus vel pretium. Donec fermentum ligula suscipit metus varius dictum. Curabitur ultrices justo at arcu cursus, sit amet iaculis dolor dapibus. Morbi semper porta nunc. Aliquam rutrum congue nunc non facilisis.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras id lacus sit amet leo feugiat venenatis. Donec mattis erat eget velit dapibus, at consequat nisi pretium. Nulla ut elementum ex, in rutrum neque. Integer eu blandit sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi vitae pulvinar odio. Morbi fermentum dolor sapien, vitae semper est maximus non. Vestibulum bibendum aliquet lacinia. Nullam sollicitudin auctor metus vel pretium. Donec fermentum ligula suscipit metus varius dictum. Curabitur ultrices justo at arcu cursus, sit amet iaculis dolor dapibus. Morbi semper porta nunc. Aliquam rutrum congue nunc non facilisis.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras id lacus sit amet leo feugiat venenatis. Donec mattis erat eget velit dapibus, at consequat nisi pretium. Nulla ut elementum ex, in rutrum neque. Integer eu blandit sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi vitae pulvinar odio. Morbi fermentum dolor sapien, vitae semper est maximus non. Vestibulum bibendum aliquet lacinia. Nullam sollicitudin auctor metus vel pretium. Donec fermentum ligula suscipit metus varius dictum. Curabitur ultrices justo at arcu cursus, sit amet iaculis dolor dapibus. Morbi semper porta nunc. Aliquam rutrum congue nunc non facilisis.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras id lacus sit amet leo feugiat venenatis. Donec mattis erat eget velit dapibus, at consequat nisi pretium. Nulla ut elementum ex, in rutrum neque. Integer eu blandit sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi vitae pulvinar odio. Morbi fermentum dolor sapien, vitae semper est maximus non. Vestibulum bibendum aliquet lacinia. Nullam sollicitudin auctor metus vel pretium. Donec fermentum ligula suscipit metus varius dictum. Curabitur ultrices justo at arcu cursus, sit amet iaculis dolor dapibus. Morbi semper porta nunc. Aliquam rutrum congue nunc non facilisis.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras id lacus sit amet leo feugiat venenatis. Donec mattis erat eget velit dapibus, at consequat nisi pretium. Nulla ut elementum ex, in rutrum neque. Integer eu blandit sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi vitae pulvinar odio. Morbi fermentum dolor sapien, vitae semper est maximus non. Vestibulum bibendum aliquet lacinia. Nullam sollicitudin auctor metus vel pretium. Donec fermentum ligula suscipit metus varius dictum. Curabitur ultrices justo at arcu cursus, sit amet iaculis dolor dapibus. Morbi semper porta nunc. Aliquam rutrum congue nunc non facilisis.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="brd_black col sticky">
        <div>
          <a href="faq.html"><img src="https://v1.iconsearch.ru/uploads/icons/crystalclear/64x64/folder_home.png" target="_blank" class="img-fluid stick_img" /></a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Try this whole code, Hopefully it'll work

Comment: You see, your solution works perfectly for both image resizing but not for "sticky" buttons which I've made with position:fixed. This is navigation buttons and i don't want to lose it's visibility for user while he scrolls text down. Is there any other ways?

Comment: @Cove I've just updated my above code. Try Once, It'll work

Comment: yeap, it works in FF but not in Safari unfortunately :(

Comment: @Cove Just add this position:-webkit-sticky!important  in the sticky css class

Comment: Doesn't helped but anyway - sticky doesn't work on IE11, but luckily, in this case, you can use fixed, which will work on both old and new browsers. https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky

Comment: @Cove Actually IE doesn't support sticky.Anyway i'm glad you found out something. If my answer helped you, mark it as correct

Comment: you really helped me a lot in understanding sticky position but unfortunately my case haven't been solved. I still have a hope that it is possible to fix my case as I wish.

Comment: @Cove :) Okay .

Answer (score 0):

remove `position:fixed;` style for your code.

Comment: But i need them to bi fixed (navigation buttons always visible while scrolling text in middle column).